# Parsing JSON values

Tags: frege

Lets say I have the following structure:

```
import Data.JSON
import Data.List

data Lang = Lang { name :: String,
                   desc :: String }

derive Show Lang

instance ToJSON Lang where
    toJSON Lang{name, desc} = 
        Struct [ 
            assoc "name" name,
            assoc "desc" desc
        ]
```

So far I could turn Lang instances to JSON:

```
langEn = Lang { name = "en", 
                desc = "english" }

langEnJSON = toJSON langEn --- produces {"name" : "en", "desc" : "english"}
```

But I can't figure out how to implement the opposite operation:

```
instance FromJSON Lang where
    fromJSON (Struct fields) = ---
```

I've read documentation first but I'm afraid I still don't get how to use `fromJSON` and use the pattern matching in this case :(

Answer (score 1):

Finally I came up with this solution:

```
instance FromJSON Lang where
 fromJSON (Struct fields)
     | Just name <- lookup "name" fields
     = case lookup "desc" fields of
           Just pdesc -> do
              fname <- fromJSON name
              fdesc <- fromJSON pdesc
              return Lang { name = fname, desc = fdesc }
           Nothing -> do
              return Lang { name = "", desc = "" }
     | otherwise = fail "error"

fromJSON _ = fail "error" --- Updated 28/10/2015
```

Now I can parse an incoming String like:

```
--- returns "english"
case (parseJSON "{\"name\":\"en\",\"desc\":\"english\"}") of 
    Just Lang {name,desc} -> name
    _                       -> ""
```

**UPDATED 28/10/2015**

Like Ingo mentioned in a comment. I should add the `fromJSON _ =...` answer in order to complete this answer, otherwise compiler warns about the refutability of my function.

Comment: See, you had it faster than I did! Please heed the compiler warning: supply an equation that fails for everything that is not a Struct. Otherwise, your program will abort on wrong input. (Try "[]")

Comment: Definitely your answer is the kind of solution I was looking for :-) I'm taking a closer look at your comment and answer and then I'll edit my answer to add your suggestion. Thanks Ingo.

Comment: Your question turned up an important point rgd. the doc - it doesn't mention the "fields" function in the examples, but it should. I wrote the doc first (as oftentimes recommended), and later it appeared to me that "field" (which is just a small generalization of Data.List.lookup, plus a fromJSON applied to the found value) could be quite usable. So I will include it in the docs also.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
instance FromJSON Lang where
  fromJSON v = case v  of
    Struct s → do
           name ← field "name" s
           desc ← field "desc" s
           return Lang{name, desc}
    _   →  fail ("expected {\"name\" : ..., \"desc\" : ...}, found " ++ show v)
```

Note that this allows some input like:

```
{"name" : "pl", "desc" : "polskij", "script" : "latin"}
```

If you want to be pedantic, you could as well match the association list that follows the `Struct` more explicitly:

```
fromJSON (Struct s) = case sort s of  
    [("desc", desc), ("name", name)] -> do
         sname <- fromJSON name
         sdesc <- fromJSON desc
         return Lang{name=sname, desc=sdesc}
    _ -> fail "extra or missing fields"
fromJSON _ = fail "I want a struct!!!"
```